# Virtual Pascal v2.1 has a small display in Win7 [64bit] - can I make it bigger?

Tags: pascal

Is there some way [software or VM] that will let me run VP in a larger box - this is really frustrating me.

I thought, from the display, that VP21 was running in DOS, so I tried "DOSBOX", but when I tried to run the VP.exe file, it came back with:
"This program must be run under Win32", so it seems to be Windows with a weird display.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to change the setting in VP: set Options->Environment->Screen Size to "Keep original".  Then exit VP, size the window the way you want it, and run VP again.

From the command line, you can do it with the mode command:

```
mode 120,60
```

is nice and large.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple (or I missed something obvious): Make a shortcut for vp.exe and edit the proporties. You can change the layout/window size to any values that your monitor allows.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can - the app itself preventing full screen mode. And you cannot use DOSBOX because VP21 is a true Win32bit app. You *can* download and install "real" TurboPascal - that one will run under DOSBOX and that you can expand full screen.